# Limit TextView boundaries to ImageView upon user touch

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, ontouchlistener

I have an imageview which only takes up a portion of the screen. And I have a textview on top of the imageview. When the user touches the textview, they can drag it to where ever they want on the screen. However, I want to limit the user to only be able to move the textview on the imageview.

When the textview is moved to the top or right side of the screen it automatically blocks it from going any further (similar to if you move your computer mouse to the top or left side of the screen). I want to try to mimic this effect just in the bounds of the imageview.

I have tried numerous techniques like getting the size of the imageview and comparing it to the y and x values and if the textview would go past this point it would equal this point. However, no success so far.

This is my current code (within the OnTouchListener()):

```
    if (touchY >= imageHeight){
                    params.leftMargin = leftSideText;//sets the margin so the textview is displayed on the screen according to them because its aligned to top and left
                    params.topMargin = (tvOne.getHeight()) - imageHeight;
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                    tvOne.setLayoutParams(params);
                }
```

where some of the variables are:

```
                touchX = (int) eventTwo.getRawX();
                touchY = (int) eventTwo.getRawY();
                //helps make the edit text start where the user touches the screen rather than that just being the top corner
                int editTextWidth = tvOne.getWidth() / 2;
                int editTextHeight = tvOne.getHeight() / 2;

                topText = touchY - editTextHeight;
                leftSideText = touchX - editTextWidth;
```

This code just makes the textview disappear once it goes past this point.

So, to clear up what I'm asking, how do you limit textview boundaries to the range of an imageview? If you could provide any help or suggestions it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:** I found the reason to my problem, yet, I have not found the solution. First, it seems the textview is not disappearing its just not visible on the black background below the image. Second, the reason why the textview is going past the imageview is because the full image is not being displayed, or so it seems. So, when I get the height its referring to the whole image height, yet, the whole image is not being displayed.

Take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203957/scaling-down-bitmap-causes-portion-of-image-not-visible)